# How make a TableView automatically change its height based on its content in JavaFX？

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

If the Table has more content, it displays its content within a ScrollPane.

If the TableView has less content, it fills itself with empty space.
How to achieve adaptive？

I can't use fixedCellSize，because my cell is wrapping.

Comment: Please post [mre] reproducing the problem.

Comment: Perhaps, in this case, it may be better to use a `GridPane` layout rather than a `TableView`.

Answer (score 0):

We do this for Width just try it for Height

```
if(TableData.size() < 15) {// Format TableView to display Vertical ScrollBar
        ptable.setPrefWidth(336);// 19 is the off set
    }else {
        ptable.setPrefWidth(355);
    }   ptable.setItems(TableData);
```